# Python Sql İmport Data String

Tags: python, sql, import

I can't enter data into sql. I tried everything but i get this error.

x.execute (" INSERT INTO ords VALUES ('%s', '%s' '%s')" %'f' %'test' %'try' ) TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

```
import mysql.connector`enter code here`
conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='1234', host='localhost', database='neworder')

x = conn.cursor()
x.execute("SELECT *  FROM ords")
x.execute (" INSERT INTO ords VALUES ('%s', '%s' '%s')" %'f' %'test' %'try' )
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Can you give us more details about what you are trying to insert?
The actual input and the expected output would be a good start.

Comment: i have try everythin first column is number second column is url third column is quantity i create sql and  table with mysql workbench.İ take error every try to mysql

Comment: You need to replace `%'f'` `%'test'` and `%'try'` by actual values, it should look like `x.execute (" INSERT INTO ords VALUES ('%s', '%s' '%s')" % (f, test, try))`

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Remove the space between `x.execute` and the parenthesis:
`x.execute("INSERT INTO ords VALUES ('%s', '%s' '%s')" % (f, test, try))`

Comment: it's not working i try rome virgule 
i am remove virgule when not enough arguments for format string

Comment: Can you please try this: `x.execute("INSERT INTO ords VALUES ({}, {}, {})".format(f, test, try))`

Comment: @Oguzhan bu sorunla bende karşılaştım mysql kullanırken bu id kısmından kaynaklı auto_increment özelliğini ekle ve ilk ekleme için manuel olarak ekle yani id'si 0 olan bir veri ekle ardından yine çalışmazsa insert into kısmına manuel olarak id yi eklemen gerekecek user.id gibi oturum olayı kullanıosan